# How to draw a circular arc / hallow sector in pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet

I desperately trying to draw circular arc / hallow sector in pyglet.
E.g from this post where ArcType.ROUND is shown
https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/issues/349

This gives me a filled sector:
`Sector(x=200, y=200, radius=200, segments=200, angle=22.5, start_angle=0)`

This gives me only the line/circular arc - without the lines of the size r to the center:
`Arc(px, py, radius, 50, tau, 0)`

What I need is:
[image]

PS: It comes to my attention that `pip install pyglet=2.0.10` with python 3.10 give me a "broken" package on my windows 10 machine. The `Arc` could not be drawn at all. Installing pyglet from source solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own function to draw the arc and two lines from its endpoints to the centre. If your trigonometry is a little rusty, the implementation is in the [linked issue](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/issues/349). The generic formulae are:

```
start_x = x + radius * math.cos(start_angle)
start_y = y + radius * math.sin(start_angle)
end_x = x + radius * math.cos(angle + start_angle)
end_y = y + radius * math.sin(angle + start_angle)
```

Then you need to define your own `draw_hollow_sector` function and it'll look something like this:
[image: Hollow Sectors]

It includes a filled sector so that you can see the hollow sector outlines it correctly.

Here's the full code listing, note that it has been autoformatted with [black](https://github.com/psf/black).

```
import pyglet
import math


def draw_hollow_sector(
    x,
    y,
    radius,
    angle=6.283185307179586,
    start_angle=0,
    color=(255, 255, 255, 255),
    batch=None,
    group=None,
):
    """Draw an arc joined by two lines from its endpoints to the center to form a hollow sector"""
    # calculate sector line coordinates
    start_x = x + radius * math.cos(start_angle)
    start_y = y + radius * math.sin(start_angle)
    end_x = x + radius * math.cos(angle + start_angle)
    end_y = y + radius * math.sin(angle + start_angle)
    # draw the arc
    arc = pyglet.shapes.Arc(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        radius=radius,
        angle=angle,
        start_angle=start_angle,
        color=color,
        closed=False,
        batch=batch,
        group=group,
    )
    # draw sector lines
    start_arc_line = pyglet.shapes.Line(
        x, y, start_x, start_y, color=color, batch=batch, group=group
    )
    end_arc_line = pyglet.shapes.Line(
        x, y, end_x, end_y, color=color, batch=batch, group=group
    )
    # need to return shapes to ensure they're not garbage collected
    return arc, start_arc_line, end_arc_line


window = pyglet.window.Window(caption="Hollow Sectors")
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
x, y = 200, 200
angle = math.pi / 3
start_angle = 1
radius = 70

sector = pyglet.shapes.Sector(
    x, y, radius=radius, angle=angle, start_angle=start_angle, batch=batch
)
hollow_shapes = draw_hollow_sector(
    x,
    y,
    radius=radius,
    angle=angle,
    start_angle=start_angle,
    color=(255, 0, 0, 255),
    batch=batch,
)
hollow_shapes += draw_hollow_sector(
    300,
    300,
    radius=110,
    angle=2.7,
    start_angle=0.6,
    color=(255, 255, 0, 255),
    batch=batch,
)
hollow_shapes += draw_hollow_sector(
    200,
    180,
    radius=125,
    angle=5.1,
    start_angle=-4.1,
    color=(255, 0, 255, 255),
    batch=batch,
)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()
```